# AWS PHP2 SDK - Creating Route53 Weighted Record Set

Tags: php, sdk, amazon-web-services, recordset

I'm using AWS PHP2 API to create a weighted record set:

```
array("Action"=>"CREATE",
      "ResourceRecordSet"=>array("Name"=>"sub.mydomain.com",
            "Type"=>"CNAME",
            "TTL"=>60,
            "ResourceRecords"=>array(array("Value"=>"address_value")),
            "Weight"=>1,
            "SetIdentifier"=>"some id"));
```

**Here is the error I'm getting**:

*AWS Error Code: InvalidInput, Status Code: 400, AWS Request ID: xx-xx-xx-xxxx, AWS Error Type: client, AWS Error Message: Invalid XML ; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'Weight'. One of '{"https://route53.amazonaws.com/doc/2012-12-12/":HealthCheckId}' is expected.*

Why is it looking for a HealthCheckId? From my understanding, weighted records do not require a health check (unlike failover).

Thanks!

UPDATE/SOLVED:
The solution is absurd! (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=458503)
Refer to LeeZ's response.

Comment: This is a pretty confusing error, and I think you are right about it not being required. I'd like to see the full HTTP request and response. You can use the Guzzle LogPlugin to do this. 

$route53Client->addSubscriber(\Guzzle\Plugin\Log\LogPlugin::getDebugPlugin());
Make sure to redact any sensitive information before posting them though.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE/SOLVED:**

The solution is absurd! (https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=458503) Refer to LeeZ's response.